# React-Native SQLite with pre-populated db table not found on Android App

Tags: android, react-native, sqlite

I do have a really minimalistic react-native app which should read data from a pre-populated database.

```
var SQLite = require('react-native-sqlite-storage');
SQLite.DEBUG(true);
SQLite.enablePromise(false);

const db = SQLite.openDatabase({
  name: 'config.db',
  location: 'default'
}, () => {
console.log('db connection success') 
}, () => {
console.log('db connection error')
});
```

The console says:

```
db connection success
```

if I run a qry, I do always get an error that the table could not be found:

```
db.transaction((tx) => {
  console.log('TX');
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM test',
  [],
  (tx, results) => {
    console.log(results)
    var temp = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; ++i)
      temp.push(results.rows.item(i));
      console.log(temp);
  });
});
```

Error:

```
SQLite.backgroundExecuteSqlBatch({"dbargs":{"dbname":"config.db"},"executes":[{"qid":1111,"sql":"BEGIN","params":[]},{"qid":1111,"sql":"SELECT * FROM tbl_user","params":[]}]})
    Error handler not provided:  {"code": 0, "message": "no such table: tbl_user(code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tbl_user"}
    warning - exception while invoking a callback:{"code":0,"line":116571,"column":27,"sourceURL":"http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false"}
    SQLite.backgroundExecuteSqlBatch({"dbargs":{"dbname":"config.db"},"executes":[{"qid":1111,"sql":"ROLLBACK","params":[]}]})
```

if I open the database from my Project it shows the table and the data. I put the databe into
\android\app\src\main\assets\www and \android\app\src\main\assets\

What am I doing wrong?